css counter transition doesn't work on safari
I have such a counter transition which doesn't work only on safari.
@property --total {
    syntax: '<integer>';
    initial-value: 0;
    inherits: false;
}
#total {
    transition: --total 3s;
    counter-set: num var(--total);
}
#total::after{
    content: counter(num);
}

I'm updating the property with
document.getElementById('total').style.setProperty('--total', total)


Do you mean number rather than integer? Perhaps if you could show what you are updating total to that would help - e.g. is it just adding 1 each time?

@AHaworth not actually I'm updating the value by +12 or +24. I'm directly setting the new number

Thanks, I've now managed to reproduce the problem.
